# How to detect NSTextField is in edit mode

Tags: macos, cocoa

I want to determine when my `NSTextField` subclass is in edit mode, i.e. when the cursor is present and ready to perform editing actions. I can detect when the text has actually been modified by using `controlTextDidBeginEditing`, but this is called only once the text has changed. Also I know when the field is potentially editable by using the `editable` property, but this is not the same as the field actually being in edit mode.

Comment: See [currentEditor()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nscontrol/1428980-currenteditor).

Comment: Yes. Thank you. You want to post this as an answer?